# Fread Abort 6 error

Tags: c, malloc, fread

In my code I am sending sending packets each with a 128 bytes from the text file and need to read in data from a text file (I can't just allocated a buffer and read all of it before sending because the file will be extremely large).  For some reason I am getting an Abort 6 error even when I have allocated memory.

SendIndex starts as 0 and it aborts for the first send so that shouldn't be the problem.

The problem occurs during strcpy I just don't know why.

Really confused so I would really appreciate the help.

```
struct packet packingT;
packingT.header = mpHeaderT;
packingT.data = (char*) calloc(512,sizeof(char));

char* sendString = (char*)calloc(128,sizeof(char));


FILE *file = fopen(receivedStruct->fileTitle, "rb");
if(file == NULL) {
    printf("Error - Can't Open File\n");
    exit(0);
}

fseek(file, 128*sendIndex, SEEK_SET);

fread(sendString, 128, 1,file);
fclose(file);
// sendString[128] = '\0';  <--- Still don't know if this is needed

packingT.header->seq_num = receivedStruct->nextSeqNum;

strcpy(packingT.data, sendString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is replace the final `strcpy` with `memcpy` instead.  That is, the last line should be `memcpy(packingT.data, sendString, 128);`

(Edit: The reason being that strcpy determines the length of the thing to be copied by scanning for a zero at the end.  You're reading arbitrary data, which may have zeros in the middle, and may not always end in a zero)

(Edit2: please be aware that the content of packingT.data is not terminated, so you can't use string functions on it.  Depending on what you're doing, you might need to add a terminator, or ensure one gets written to the file)